# How to allow only two letter two two numbers and two special characters but position is not fact in regular expression

Tags: regex

I have to face problem when I create a regular expression for allow only two letter two numbers and two special characters. This is actually not a problem to create a regular expression. But when i change the position of characters then regular expression show not match. So please help me how to solve these problem.

```
[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{2}[!@#$%^&]{2}
```

Comment: post you have tried

Comment: Read (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

This type of matching can best be done with look ahead:

[`^(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&].*[!@#$%^&]).{6}$`](https://regex101.com/r/Oulpj0/1)

The `(?=   )` does not grab any characters, it just looks ahead, so you can check for different conditions, and only then grab them with a simple `.{6}$` at the end, when all look-ahead conditions pass. The only condition left is that there are exactly 6 characters from the beginning (`^`) to the end (`$`).

As each sub-pattern repeats, you could also do it like this:

[`^(?=(?:.*\d){2})(?=(?:.*[A-Za-z]){2})(?=(?:.*[!@#$%^&]){2}).{6}$`](https://regex101.com/r/Oulpj0/2)

Comment: Thanks lot @ttrincot